# dplyr, calculate the max_arr_ delay for flights to ATL and BOS

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The dataset is nycflights13.R.  I'm unable to get the required answer:

1. ATL  895
2. BOS  422

When I run my code I can get the top for ATL but not for BOS, I'm having trouble narrowing down the resulting df to just the two answers.

```
flights %>%
    filter(dest == 'ATL' | dest == 'BOS') %>%
    group_by(dest) %>%
    select(dest, max_arr_delay = arr_delay) %>%
    arrange(desc(arr_delay) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

I am missing the step that would limit this dataframe.  I get both the max answers for ATL and BOS but BOS is buried by the arrange function.  How do I limit this so I get both the max values for just ATL and BOS.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::slice_max` you could do:

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  filter(dest %in% c("ATL", "BOS")) %>%
  select(dest, max_arr_delay = arr_delay) %>%
  group_by(dest) %>%
  slice_max(max_arr_delay, n = 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#> # Groups:   dest [2]
#>   dest  max_arr_delay
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 ATL             895
#> 2 BOS             422
```

Or using `summarise`:

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>%
  filter(dest %in% c("ATL", "BOS")) %>%
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarise(max_arr_delay = max(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   dest  max_arr_delay
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 ATL             895
#> 2 BOS             422
```